Screen wake-up does not work. Does it depend on the phone model or android version?
I have a problem. I need that if the phone is asleep, the activity wakes up the screen and displays on the screen over the lock. Everything works on xiaomi red me note 5, android version 9. But on the latest xiaomi 13 model (android version 14), the phone does not fall asleep, and after unlocking, only a notification is displayed, activity will be displayed only if you click on the notification
Manifest:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />

Activty in manifest
        <activity android:name=".alarm.activity.AlarmActivity"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>

In Service
  val alarmActivity = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION or      Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }

  val pendingIntentAlarmActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            120,
            alarmActivity,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

  val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "alarm_channel")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alarm_icon)
            .setContentTitle("alarm")
            .setContentText("alarm")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setTicker("Notification")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntentAlarmActivity)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
            .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntentAlarmActivity, true)
            .build()

In activity
        setShowWhenLocked(true)
        setTurnScreenOn(true)
        val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
        keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)

        requestedOrientation = SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

        val cpuWakelock = (getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "XXX:CPU_WAKE_LOCK"
        )
        cpuWakelock.acquire(10*60*1000L /*10 minutes*/)

is there anything else that needs to be specified in new versions of android to wake up the screen?

You can try using below ways to proceed : 1. Use WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
2. Use PowerManager.WakeLock
3. Use a Foreground Service
4. Handle Notifications using PendingIntent
